# Date Formatting with Html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, formatting

In my mvc application, i assign the `Date` to my view using `DisplayFor` `Htmlhelper`, like below. I tried to format like this. But, i am not successful.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(d => d.TravelAllowances.DepatureDate, "{0:dd-MM-yy}")
```

Please suggest me some way to accomplish this.

Note: `DepartureDate` is in `String` format.

Thanks
Manikandan

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Do you have to use Html.Display? Why not render it directly? @Model.TravelAllowances.DepatureDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy");

Comment: @Ulterior : cshtml file. Binding the view with Model

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Html.Display? Why not render it directly? `@Model.TravelAllowances.DepatureDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy");`

Comment: UI is completely blank. Any other idea?

Comment: @Model.TravelAllowances.DepatureDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is three years old and the OP probably found a way, but in case others stumble upon this Q/A...

The problem is that you have the date as just a string.

If you are storing it as a date and converting it to a string when populating the model being passed to the view from the controller, then format it as you want in the controller.

If you are storing date as a string (bad idea IMHO), and just populating the model property in the controller, then I would parse the string into a DateTime object and then format that DateTime into a string for the Model's property.

Just my two cents, three years late :)