# Display only Date in @Html.DisplayFor() in MVC

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I work in MVC5 and EntityFramework for displaying data into View.

right now in my view data format is :- 10/22/2014 12:00:00 AM
But i want only date :- 22/10/2014 in this format

i try this code but it not working

```
 @if (item.chekin_on_after != null)
                    { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.chekin_on_after, "ShortDateTime")}
```

I also follow few link in stackoverflow but not helpful [Date Format using Html.DisplayFor() in MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19920603/date-format-using-html-displayfor-in-mvc5), [Display only date and no time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time)

Comment: You could add the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to your property or create a custom `DisplatTemplate` to format the date

Comment: my model class generated by database, Entity Framework, if in future, i will update my DataModel then it will lost.

Comment: That why its best practice to use view models to represent the data you want to display

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I didn’t use `@html.DisplayFor()`.Instead of this I use

```
@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.chekin_on_after))
```

And it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but if you are trying to use Model binding, @Html.DisplayFor is what you normally want to use. If you are not using Model binding then your example will work.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use below attribute in your model class.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime chekin_on_after { get; set; }
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function in your controller before populating the data to model :

```
public static System.DateTime ParseDate(string value, string style)
{
    DateTime blankDate = default(DateTime);
    if ((value != null & value.Length > 0)) {
        string formattedDate = Strings.Format(Convert.ToDateTime(value), style);
        return formattedDate;
    } else {
        return blankDate;
    }
}
```

Where value is your:  `10/22/2014 12:00:00 AM` and style is :`"MM/dd/yyyy"` or something as you want

Comment: My Model and View is generated by Entity Framework and it return a **LIST** so where i put this code. I am little confuse how i use this code.